# Global profile - number of Q & A's for Area51

Tags: discussion, support, area-51

Why does the number of questions and answers show as `-` on the global stackexchange profile in the `accounts` tab? I do have several questions on few proposal sites in the definition phase and also few answers on discuss.area51. But I guess, neither of these are picked.

[image: number of q-a]

Shall not it display the number of question and answers on the discuss.area51?